# AWS Appflow - Incremental Transfer & Overwriting Existing Files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS Appflow to transfer files from a SharePoint site to an S3 bucket. My goal is to achieve the following:

- Weekly Runs: Schedule the flow to run on a weekly basis.
- Incremental Transfers: Only transfer files that have been modified since the last run.
- Overwrite Existing Files: When a file is updated in SharePoint, overwrite the existing file in the S3 bucket with the latest version, instead of creating a new subfolder with the Appflow run ID.

I've read the [AWS Appflow documentation on data partitioning and aggregation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/flows-catalog.html), and noticed references to these functionalities in previous Stack Overflow answers. However, it seems these features are no longer available.

Is there a way to achieve my desired behavior of overwriting existing files in S3 during incremental transfers with Appflow?

I've already configured Appflow for weekly incremental transfers, but it creates subfolders for each run instead of updating existing files.

Any help would be appreciated :)